# How can I do an incremental `mysqldump` without dropping table?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I'd like to fetch the last 100 rows of a table via a `mysqldump`, but I already have the rest of the table. How can I only fetch the last 100 rows for a mysqldump and then `replace` (or overwrite) any duplicates I may have?

**db1 Incremental Export**

```
mysqldump -umy_user my_db1 my_table --single-transaction --replace --where="id > 900" | pigz > my_db1-my_table.sql.gz
```

**db2 Incremental Import**

```
pv my_db1-my_table.sql.gz | gunzip | mysql -umy_user my_db2
```

Unfortunately the mysqldump above creates a `drop table my_table` query. How can I skip this?

**What I want to happen...**

Say `db2` has 950 records. And `db1` has 1000. I want records 901-1000 from `db1` on `db2`, as well as the 1-900 already on `db2` (just leave them be). Replacing/Overwriting records 901-950 on `db2` is preferred.

**What Currently Happens...**

After running the above, `db2` **only** contains records 901-1000, and is now missing 1-900 (due to `drop table`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use replace into flag (`--replace`) and where condition (`--where`)  while also omitting the create statement (`-t`):

```
mysqldump -t --replace --where="id between 901 and 1000" my_db1 table my_table
```